# IT-related synonym for "context"

Tags: synonyms, programming, internet

I'm developing an application which has an "Event" system that basically allows application extensions to attach events to a certain "context". When the application reaches a context, it will fire events that are attached to it.

Anyway, I don't like the word *context*; it sounds weird.  What alternatives do I have?

Comment: You'll have to expand that a bit. I've no idea what *"When the application reaches a context"* means - I understand "applications" to be "programs", but in what sense do they "reach" anywhere? And whether you like the word or not, you really need to tell us what you mean by "context" here.

Comment: The app goes trough a series of states. For example: 1. it starts - fires events attached to the "start" context. 2. logs in the user, fires events attached on the "login" context etc.. Basically the context represents a certain action that the app is doing

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question with "state".

Comment: So when you say *"the application reaches a context"*, it seems you mean *"the program performs an action"*, yes? I write code myself, but I wouldn't use "context" that way. To me, if my code is performing some action (i.e. - executing some function), the "context" just means the collective set of values of all "external" variables that may affect how the function operates.

Comment: yes Fumble. I think I did answer my question. "action" is good alternative :)

Comment: @MetaEd: Perzactly! Though I personally use "state" to mean the values of *all* variables (plus stuff like open file handles, network connections, etc.), whereas I usually reserve "context" for just those variables relevant to some particular lower-level function I'm dealing with (in the current *context!* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terms like *state* and *context* have been mentioned in the question and various comments, along with objections to both.  *Frame* might be suitable; this term is used in animation and video editors to denote points in a sequence where things change.  (*Sequence point* and *basic block*, or *block*, or *barrier*, are related concepts.)  If you want a term analogous to *context* but that carries no baggage from previous uses in IT, consider *[milieu](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/milieu)*, meaning a setting or environment.  Another word to consider is *thunk*, which [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thunk) inadequately defines as "a delayed computation" and "... a function or procedure taking no arguments" and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) more properly says "a piece of code to perform a delayed computation (similar to a closure)".  That is, a *thunk* is like a self-contained action unit.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if the term you are describing is ***criterion*** (plural ***criteria***).